# How do I change my default working directory for Python (Anaconda) on VSCode?

Tags: python, file, visual-studio-code, anaconda, working-directory

So I have been trying to open very basic files like this: `inputFile = open("keywords.txt", "r")`

But I get this error:

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'keywords.txt'
```

This must be because Python's default working directory is not the one where my .py file is (correct me if i'm wrong). 
How can I find the exact path of the directory I'm working in and then change Python's default working directory to it?

Note: I'm on *OSX Mojave* using *VSCode* and *Anaconda (Python 3.6)*

Answer (score 2):

We have to distinguish the **two** notions: the "`working directory`" and the "`python environment`".
When you go into `VS code` from `Anaconda`, then you are in an `Anaconda virtual python environment` and it's  default `directory`.

You can test it with upon-left first icon - "**Explorer**".
Here you will find a directory structure, where your `.py` file actually is. 
But sometimes the file what the `.py` searching for could be in some quite other directory. If you want to run a python program with some additional files stored in a common directory, then I prefer to use some variable to set the working directory:

```
work_dir = "path/to/working_directory"
```

The use

```
import os
path = os.join(work_dir, somefile.txt)
```

If the files the python program uses are in a complex directory structure, then changing the working directory won't be a solution.
Though when the programmer uses relative paths, it can be.

In VS Code has a **terminal** where you can check the current Anaconda environment and directory in a bash shell manner.
When you run the program you will see what environment and options your `.py` file is actually running in and with.

Answer (score -1):

By default Python's "current working directory" is the folder which it is placed in. Though this might be different when using Anaconda

This will print your current directory

```
import os
print(os.getcwd())
```

This will change your directory

```
os.chdir('Your new file path here')
```

Then do another `print(os.getcwd())` to make sure it worked